# Updates to Type and State fields break model retrieval from WSAPI

Tags: javascript, rally

It seems that the upcoming update to the Type and State fields will be breaking the combobox in the Rally Portfolio Item Kanban Board app, as well as cause issues loading the States.

Here are the two affected code snippets that I would like to get some clarification on how to update:

```
this.typeCombo = Ext.widget('rallycombobox', {
    fieldLabel:'Type:',
    labelWidth:30,
    labelClsExtra:'rui-label',
    stateful:false,
    margin: '0 10 0 0',
    storeConfig:{
        autoLoad:true,
        remoteFilter:false,
        model:'Type',
        sorters:{
            property:'ordinalValue',
            direction:'Asc'
        },
        cls:'typeCombo',
        defaultSelectionToFirst:false,
        context:this.getContext().getDataContext()
    }
});
```

and

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model:'State',
    context:this.getContext().getDataContext(),
    autoLoad:true,
    fetch:['Name', 'WIPLimit', 'Description'],
    filters:[
        {
            property:'StateType',
            value:this.currentType
        },
        {
            property:'Enabled',
            value:true
        }
    ],
    sorters:[
        {
            property:'OrderIndex',
            direction:'ASC'
        }
    ],
    listeners:{
        load:function (store, records) {
            if (options.success) {
                options.success.call(options.scope || this, records);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The next release should fix this.  As soon as 1.37 is out (9/1) it should start working again.

Comment: So are you saying that none of the code above will need to be changed in order to support the new structure?

Comment: 2.0p3 will be released soon along with 1.37 (on 9/1). p3 includes Rally.ui.combobox.PortfolioItemTypeComboBox, which can replace the first code example. Check out this help file for how the underlying wsapi queries have changed: https://www.rallydev.com/help/portfolio-item-query-changes

Comment: You should post that as an answer, so that I can accept it, even though there is definitely a lot more work to be done to migrate to p3.